# VB.NET Checkboxes checking

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a form which contains a checkbox field. On page load I want to create a separate checkbox for each customer in my Database. The code I have to create the checkboxes for each customer works fine. However, I also want to check in the database if the customer is set to unauthorized if they are then I want to check there box. I also have code for the case where the user checks a box. If a box is checked I update the database setting the unauthorized attribute to true. My problem is when I check a box it works fine and the box is checked, however if I reload the page all the boxes are unchecked. So either my database update is not updating the database or the way I check on page load for checked boxes is incorrect. Any ideas?

The code for the asp checkbox field:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList id="check1" AutoPostBack="True" TextAlign="Right" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Check" runat="server">

</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

The Code for the page load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT Name, unauthorized, ID FROM Customer ORDER BY Name"
    Dim dt As DataTable = db.execDataTableQuery(sql, "Customer")
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                check1.Items.Add(New ListItem(CStr(dt.Rows(i).Item("Name"))))
                check1.Items(i).Value = CInt(dt.Rows(i).Item("ID"))
                check1.Items(i).Text = CStr(dt.Rows(i).Item("Name"))
                If CInt(dt.Rows(i).Item("unauthorized")) = 1 Then
                    check1.Items(i).Selected = 1
                Else
                    check1.Items(i).Selected = 0
                End If
            Next

        End Sub
```

The code to update the database:

```
    Sub Check(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim sql As String
        If check1.SelectedItem.Selected = 1 Then
            sql = "UPDATE Customer SET unauthorized = 1 WHERE ID = @ID"
            db.execUpdateQuery(sql, New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ID", check1.SelectedItem.Value))
        Else
            sql = "UPDATE Customer SET unauthorized = 0 WHERE ID = @ID"
            db.execUpdateQuery(sql, New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@ID", check1.SelectedItem.Value))
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap you code in Page_Load in a `Not Page.IsPostback`, otherwise on postback no events are triggered and the selection is lost since you're overwriting it from database.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostback Then
        ' databind your CheckBoxList '
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I had that before but it made no difference

Comment: I seem to have fixed it by switching my true and false around. Also, for my code to update when an item is selected, is there a better way of doing that?